# Handling entities when using SAX with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, sax

I'm trying to parse a file called JMnedict.xml, which is a dictionary of Japanese names. Hopefully the non-ASCII characters aren't causing any problems with the parsing, but I can't rule out the possibility. The original file is linked to from http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/enamdict_doc.html , but it's very large.

Because the XML file is so large, I'm using SAX.

When parsing the original file, with the following debugging code that uses SAX, it looks like it works until it comes across the first entity, and then stops working. In particular, you don't see the elements starting and ending once it encounters its first error.

```
# sax_replication.rb
require "nokogiri"

class SaxReplication
  def self.parse(filename)
    parser = Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Parser.new(EnamdictDocument.new)
    parser.parse(File.open(filename))
  end
end

class EnamdictDocument < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  def start_element(name, attributes = [])
    puts "DEBUG: #{name} started"
  end

  def end_element(name)
    puts "DEBUG: #{name} ended"
  end

  def error(string)
    puts "ERROR: #{string}"
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  filename = ARGV[0]
  SaxReplication.parse(filename)
end
```

gives

```
$ ruby sax_replication.rb data/JMnedict.xml | head -n20
DEBUG: JMnedict started
DEBUG: entry started
DEBUG: k_ele started
DEBUG: keb started
DEBUG: keb ended
DEBUG: k_ele ended
DEBUG: r_ele started
DEBUG: reb started
DEBUG: reb ended
DEBUG: r_ele ended
DEBUG: trans started
DEBUG: name_type started
ERROR: Entity 'given' not defined
ERROR: Entity 'fem' not defined
ERROR: Entity 'fem' not defined
ERROR: Entity 'given' not defined
ERROR: Entity 'fem' not defined
ERROR: Entity 'given' not defined
ERROR: Entity 'fem' not defined
ERROR: Entity 'surname' not defined
```

I suspect that it's something to do with SAX, because if I use a manually created file that is much smaller, it works with a conventional parser, but not with a SAX parser.

```
$ ruby sax_replication.rb data/tinyJMnedict.xml
DEBUG: JMnedict started
DEBUG: entry started
DEBUG: k_ele started
DEBUG: keb started
DEBUG: keb ended
DEBUG: k_ele ended
DEBUG: r_ele started
DEBUG: reb started
DEBUG: reb ended
DEBUG: r_ele ended
DEBUG: trans started
DEBUG: name_type started
ERROR: Entity 'given' not defined
```

(The results of using a conventional XML parsing)

```
# conventional_xml.rb
require "nokogiri"

class ConventionalXML
  def self.parse(filename)
    text = File.read(filename)
    nokogiri = Nokogiri::XML(text)
    trans_det_xpath = '/JMnedict/entry/trans/trans_det'
    trans_det_node = nokogiri.xpath(trans_det_xpath).first
    content = trans_det_node.content
    puts content
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  filename = ARGV[0]
  ConventionalXML.parse(filename)
end

$ ruby conventional_xml.rb data/tinyJMnedict.xml
Chusen
```

There seems to be a description of the entities in the XML file.

The following is the data/tinyJMnedict.xml file I used, and it contains a description of the entities.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE JMnedict [
<!--
        This is the DTD of the Japanese-Multilingual Named Entity
        Dictionary file. It is based on the JMdict DTD, and carries
        many fields from it. It is used for a quick-and-dirty conversion
        of the ENAMDICT entries, plus the name entries from EDICTH.
-->
<!ELEMENT JMnedict (entry*)>
<!--                                                                   -->
<!ELEMENT entry (k_ele*, r_ele+, trans+)*>
        <!-- Entries consist of kanji elements, reading elements 
        name translation elements. Each entry must have at 
        least one reading element and one sense element. Others are optional.
        -->
<!ELEMENT k_ele (keb, ke_inf*, ke_pri*)>
        <!-- The kanji element, or in its absence, the reading element, is 
        the defining component of each entry.
        The overwhelming majority of entries will have a single kanji
        element associated with an entity name in Japanese. Where there are 
        multiple kanji elements within an entry, they will be orthographical
        variants of the same word, either using variations in okurigana, or
        alternative and equivalent kanji. Common "mis-spellings" may be 
        included, provided they are associated with appropriate information
        fields. Synonyms are not included; they may be indicated in the
        cross-reference field associated with the sense element.
        -->
<!ELEMENT keb (#PCDATA)>
        <!-- This element will contain an entity name in Japanese 
        which is written using at least one non-kana character (usually
        kanji, but can be other characters). The valid 
        characters are kanji, kana, related characters such as chouon and 
        kurikaeshi, and in exceptional cases, letters from other alphabets.
        -->
<!ELEMENT ke_inf (#PCDATA)>
        <!-- This is a coded information field related specifically to the 
        orthography of the keb, and will typically indicate some unusual
        aspect, such as okurigana irregularity.
        -->
<!ELEMENT ke_pri (#PCDATA)>
        <!-- This and the equivalent re_pri field are provided to record
        information about the relative priority of the entry, and are for
        use either by applications which want to concentrate on entries of 
        a particular priority, or to generate subset files. The reason
        both the kanji and reading elements are tagged is because on
        occasions a priority is only associated with a particular
        kanji/reading pair.
        -->
<!--                                                                   -->
<!ELEMENT r_ele (reb, re_restr*, re_inf*, re_pri*)>
        <!-- The reading element typically contains the valid readings
        of the word(s) in the kanji element using modern kanadzukai. 
        Where there are multiple reading elements, they will typically be
        alternative readings of the kanji element. In the absence of a 
        kanji element, i.e. in the case of a word or phrase written
        entirely in kana, these elements will define the entry.
        -->
<!ELEMENT reb (#PCDATA)>
        <!-- this element content is restricted to kana and related
        characters such as chouon and kurikaeshi. Kana usage will be
        consistent between the keb and reb elements; e.g. if the keb
        contains katakana, so too will the reb.
        -->
<!ELEMENT re_restr (#PCDATA)>
        <!-- This element is used to indicate when the reading only applies
        to a subset of the keb elements in the entry. In its absence, all
        readings apply to all kanji elements. The contents of this element 
        must exactly match those of one of the keb elements.
        -->
<!ELEMENT re_inf (#PCDATA)>
        <!-- General coded information pertaining to the specific reading.
        Typically it will be used to indicate some unusual aspect of 
        the reading. -->
<!ELEMENT re_pri (#PCDATA)>
        <!-- See the comment on ke_pri above. -->
<!ELEMENT trans (name_type*, trans_det*)>
        <!-- The trans element will record the translational equivalent
        of the Japanese name, plus other related information. 
        -->
<!ELEMENT name_type (#PCDATA)>
        <!-- The type of name, recorded in the appropriate entity codes.
        -->
<!ELEMENT trans_det (#PCDATA)>
        <!-- The actual translations of the name, usually as a transcription
        into the target language.
        -->
<!ATTLIST trans_det xml:lang CDATA #IMPLIED>
        <!-- The xml:lang attribute defines the target language of the
        translated name. It will be coded using the three-letter language 
        code from the ISO 639-2 standard. When absent, the value "eng" 
        (i.e. English) is the default value. The bibliographic (B) codes
        are used.-->
<!-- The following entity codes are used for common elements within the
various information fields.
-->
<!ENTITY surname "family or surname">
<!ENTITY place "place name">
<!ENTITY unclass "unclassified name">
<!ENTITY company "company name">
<!ENTITY product "product name">
<!ENTITY masc "male given name or forename">
<!ENTITY fem "female given name or forename">
<!ENTITY person "full name of a particular person">
<!ENTITY given "given name or forename, gender not specified">
<!ENTITY station "railway station">
<!ENTITY organization "organization name">
<!ENTITY oik "old or irregular kana form">
]>
<!-- JMnedict created: 2014-05-05 -->
<JMnedict>
<entry>
<k_ele>
<keb>ゝ泉</keb>
</k_ele>
<r_ele>
<reb>ちゅせん</reb>
</r_ele>
<trans>
<name_type>&given;</name_type>
<trans_det>Chusen</trans_det>
</trans>
</entry>
</JMnedict>
```

The entities in name_type elements contain somewhat useful information, but I could ignore them if necessary.

How do I avoid the entities causing errors for parsing with SAX in Nokogiri?

Comment: I found this quote in the [libxml docs](http://xmlsoft.org/entities.html): “WARNING: handling entities on top of the libxml2 SAX interface is difficult!!! If you plan to use non-predefined entities in your documents, then the learning curve to handle then using the SAX API may be long. If you plan to use complex documents, I strongly suggest you consider using the DOM interface instead and let libxml deal with the complexity rather than trying to do it yourself.” It looks like Nokogiri hasn’t implemented entites in SAX parsing.

Comment: @matt is there any work-around if there's only a very small number of entities, which are known in advance?